# Contol M scheduling concept

Tags: control-m

Job A runs Mon-Fri and triggers job B. However, I want Job B to run every day. How can I ensure Job B runs on Saturday and Sunday, even though it is set up to only run after Job A completes?

Comment: Please show some examples of what you have tried. Please explain a little more on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

What we did for the similar issue is we created a job that rolls in only on weekends. This job might not have any IN-condition or can be timer dependent.
Let's call this job 'JOB_WEEKEND'.

JOB_WEEKEND out condition:
   *JOB_WEEKEND-OK*

Now the Job B should have these conditions
*JOB A-OK or JOB_WEEKEND_OK*

This you can select from 'IN conditon relationships' below the conditions tab. This weekend job can be used for any other similar jobs too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Control-M version 8, then you can use adjust condition option by using smart folders instead of creating a new dummy job.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give '@' before the IN condition of job B for Job A as below:-

IN     @-JOB A--JOB B

while giving this condition, it means that job B will wait if there is a job A (from Mon- Fri). However, on weekend (SAT & SUN) the job B will not wait for Job A.

Comment: @(table for A)-JOB A-(table for B)- JOB B